# Can I get the properties of a file using node.js the same way I can by right clicking and selecting "Properties"?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Windows, when you right click on a file, you can select "Properties" from the dropdown that's shown. You can then navigate to a "Details" tab and see a lot of information about the file; like *Title*, *Subtitle*, *Rating*, *Length*, *Bit Rate*, *Size*, *File Location*, and *Type*. Is there a way to access all this information using Node.js?

`fs.stats(myDirectory)` does not return all of this information.

Comment: That sounds like meta information in a media file. Surely you can read such [ID3 tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) and [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata#Digital_music) from the file itself using nodejs

Comment: As of yet, I have not found a node module that can achieve this. That’s why I asked the question.

Comment: Well you asked whether it is possible. Asking for libraries is off-topic on StackOverflow. I suggest you use some other tool to inspect the concrete files you're interested in to find out which kind of meta tags they use, then search for the technical term. I'm sure you'll find something.